# max #process for nginx sync to php-fpm

Tags: nginx, php-fpm

Apart from memory and cpu limitations, I'd like to keep in mind another number for the nginx and php-fpm setup.

If there is process.max set in /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf, the max number of php process ready for serving is limited.

However, nginx never knows about this limit and tries to find and get served by another php-fpm process.

How to limit nginx to request the same max at the same moment? (independent from cpu/ram which is discussed and explained in lots of other posts)

Answer (score 0):

nginx doesn't spawn the php-fpm workers, it doesn't need to know about the limit.

Comment: that's the conflict, isn't it? nginx will try to get even more php process' though the max number is limited and will never be more because of php-fpm's config. i wonder how this could be considered in order to have nginx not ending up in errors 502 if the number is exceeded.

Comment: Having 2 workers doesn't mean that if you get 3 simultaneous requests the last one will 502, it just gets queued until it can be handled.

Comment: The queue seems to fail or break. Whenever the request can't be served quickly enough, nginx error `recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client:` and `WARNING: The maximum number of processes has been reached.` suggesting to consider max values. but that's not wanted. instead, i want it to wait, not to request even more at the same time or http deny with err code 502, also fail :-(

Comment: The problem is not in nginx or its configuration. The error message indicates that php-fpm closed the connection, you should try to find out why.

Comment: though php-fpm config is set to log level=notice, it only tells about `WARNING: [pool www] seems busy (you may need to increase pm.start_servers, or pm.min/max_spare_servers)`. it reached maximum, so i'd expect it to use a queue - not disconnect nginx.

Comment: @ledy php-fpm is very buggy to say the least (especially on any type of VM). I actually stopped using it recently because I could not figure out why it was causing the same error you posted. No matter the amount of start processes / children I set, dynamic or static etc the issue was still there. I had been working on that issue for a number of months and finally got fed up with it and now I just use the fcgi bin.